# Config registry - how to implement

Tags: php, oop, object, static, config

I am after some input/guidance.. I have an application that uses a central configuration registry as show below..

The application parses a config directory for ini files and sets the arrays into the class using the name of the file as the index, as well as single configuration variables when required..

I can see a few problems arising including:

1. Name clashes between files and vars set within the script
2. The inability to pull nested array variables resulting in the following code:

   $databases = config::get('database');
    $actual_record = $databases['default'];

I was tempted to add a 2nd get parameter for the nested value, however what happens in the future if i need to pull a 3rd or 4th level value.

```
class config
{
   private static $registry;

   /**
   *
   */
   private function __construct() {}

   /**
   *
   */
   public static function get($key)
   {
      if (isset(self::$registry[$key])) return self::$registry[$key];
      else return FALSE;
   }

   /**
   *
   */
   public static function set($key, $value, $overwrite = FALSE)
   {
      // Does the variable already exist?
      if (isset(self::$registry[$key]) && $overwrite === FALSE) 
         throw new Exception();

      self::$registry[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help..

Comment: You could encapsulate each entry into an object which has methods to retrieve values again. `config::getNested('database')->get('default')`. Alternatively how about not nesting them if that is possible? How about separating them with a dot? `config::get('database.default')`

Comment: This may be a silly question but how do you turn the database.default notation into an array call?

Comment: tokenize the identifier and split it at the dots. if you don't have a dot it's a plain call, otherwise take the array at the field with the name of the first parameter and the field specified by the parameter behind the first dot and so on. If you like the idea I can post some code in an answer.

Comment: Thanks Dan, yea i like the idea.. A coding example would be awesome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in the comments here is the code to make the dot separated names working. There might be a more efficient solution, I just threw this together for you.

```
class Config
{
    private
        $registry
    ;

    public function __construct($registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

   public function get($identifier)
   {
        return $this->resolve(explode('.', $identifier), $this->registry);
    }

    private function resolve($entries, $in)
    {
        if(key_exists($entries[0], $in) && count($entries) > 1)
        {
            // We have more than one level to resolve
            $newIn = $in[$entries[0]];
            unset($entries[0]);
            return $this->resolve(array_values($entries), $newIn);
        }
        elseif(key_exists($entries[0], $in) && count($entries) == 1)
        {
            // We are at the bottom, let's return.
            return $in[$entries[0]];
        }
        // If we get here something went wrong.
        throw new Exception('Entry could not be resolved.');
    }
}

$cfg = new Config(
    array(
        'plain' => 'plain entry',
        'nested'    =>  array(
            'first' =>  'nested, first entry',
            'second'    =>  array(
                'third' =>  'deeper nested entry'
            )
        )
    )
);

print_r($cfg->get('plain'))."\n";
print_r($cfg->get('nested.first'))."\n";
print_r($cfg->get('nested.second.third'))."\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you could add a new instance of `config` again if there are multiple values on the next level.

A configuration like this

```
value.second = a
value.third = b
other.value.my = a
other.value.foo = b
```

Would then result in a class tree like this (`config` always is an instance of the class and intendation means that something is in the attributes array of the `config` instance above; texts before the `=>` are index names, with which you will access them).

```
config
    value => config
        second => a
        third => b
    other => config
        value => config
            my => a
            foo => b
```

I hope you can grasp a bit what I mean.

Then you could implement either [ArrayAccess](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/interfaceArrayAccess.html) or [magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) `__get` and `__set` for one of the following methods to access your values:

```
config->value->second
config->other->value->my
```

or

```
config['value']['second']
config['other']['value']['my']
```